# How to find out the remaining value on a Charlie Ticket?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, boston

I am wondering if there is any way to find the remaining value on a Boston [Charlie Ticket](https://mbta.com/fares/payment-methods)?  I have several "left over" and would like to know if they have stored dollars on them.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Seems like a reasonable enough question.

Comment: This is not obvious either. It used to be on the MBTA website, but they recently "redesigned" it and this information got lost.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I would think the easiest way to check would be the same way you check the remaining value on basically any stored value card. If the remaining value isn't printed on the card itself, just run it through a reader or vending machine next time you are at a station. Charlie Tickets aren't registered centrally, so there's basically no other way other than to read the physical card.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert them into any fare vending machine at any subway or commuter rail station to see what value, if any, is on them. At this time there is no way to check the value online (and likely never will be).

Comment: I asked MBTA about this and there response was in line with what your answer. `MyCharlie Card account can only registar CharlieCards were (sp) you can check fare. If you would like to check the fare for a Charlie Ticket you will have to go to a Fare Vending Machine at an MBTA Station.`